# Django: How to get a named related field in a template

Tags: django

I have a Django app where the main model is Bugs.

I have a second Model called Scrub, that has a FK pointing to the Bugs model.

```
class Scrub(models.Model):
    bug_id = models.ForeignKey(Bugs,related_name='scrublines')
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    time = models.DateTimeField()
    field = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.bug_id)
```

From the shell, I can add new Scrub entries,.

```
>>> B = Bugs.objects.get(bug_id=66045)
>>> U = User.objects.get(pk=2)
>>> B.scrublines.create(user=U,time=datetime.datetime.now(),field="field1",value='value1')
<Scrub: 66045>
>>> B.scrublines.create(user=U,time=datetime.datetime.now(),field="field2",value='value2')
<Scrub: 66045>
>>> B.scrublines.create(user=U,time=datetime.datetime.now(),field="field3",value='value3')
<Scrub: 66045>
```

I can walk through all of the fields by getting all, and iterating

```
>>> lines = B.scrublines.all()
>>> for line in lines:
...   print("%s:%s" % (line.field,line.value))
... 
field1:value1
field2:value2
field3:value3
```

What I want to do from the template, is get a specific related line, by specifying the field name.  I can get that from the shell

```
>>> B.scrublines.get(field='field1').value
u'value1'
```

The template walks through all of the bugs, and places each field into a different table cell, and I want to add the value from field1, field2, field3 directly into the cells.

```
{% for bug in bugs %}
<tr class="bugrow" >
    <td>{{bug.bug_id}}</td>
```

Can I get a related line by specifying the field name in the template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Django template language, the dot notation can be a dictionary lookup. E.g.  `{{ foo.bar }}` will be treated as `foo['bar']`.

Using Python we can transform this into a function call of sorts...

```
class MyGetter(object):

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return "Trying to get {}".format(item)

def home(req):
    return render(req, "hello.html", {"stuff": MyGetter()})
```

And in `hello.html`, if you have something like this:

```
<p>{{ stuff.foo }}</p>
```

You'll see the message "Trying to get foo" appear on the page. Basically all you need to do is modify the body of `__getitem__` to suit your purposes. (And, of course, come up with appropriate names for everything.)

There are other ways to do this (i.e. `__getattr__`) but I think using `__getitem__` is the most clear.

Furthermore, you could *also* use custom template tags/template filters if you like. It's all up to you. This is how I would do it, since it seems to involve the fewest number of moving parts.

### TL;DR

Try this:

```
class FieldReader(object):

    def __init__(self, bug):
        self.__bug = bug

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return self.__bug.scrublines.get(field=item).value
```

In your template, you can use

```
{{ field_reader.field1 }}
```

to get the value of `field1` for whatever `Bug` you sent to the `FieldReader` constructor.

Comment: That worked well when I supplied the name of the field manually.  Is there a way to do this using the {{bug}} variable in the template?

Comment: There are a few strategies you could use: you could monkey-patch an attribute onto the `bug` object directly (e.g. `bugs.fields.field1`), or you can loop over tuples of `(bug, field_reader)` instead of looping over instances of `bug`.

Comment: The problem is that the fields will always be changing.  They are saved in the database with the name format as <bug>-<branch>-allow-version, so "bug" and "branch" will be different for each bug.  I would need to do something like {{field_reader.{{bug}}-{{branch}}-allow-version}} to use the function but I tried that and it didn't work.  Since this was the best answer to the question I asked, it is the accepted answer, but I will need to figure out a different way to get what I need.

Comment: With dot notation you are restricted to using strings that work as Python variable names, so if your strings include hyphens, you will *need* to use either a template tag or filter, which will let you pass string arguments.

But as for your suggestion (with nested template variables) you shouldn't be thinking of trying to use the templates in such an "advanced" way. Cook your data in your view so when it gets to your template it's easy to use.

Comment: For example, in your view, loop through your `bug` objects and do `bug.fields = FieldReader(bug)`. Then you can do `bug.fields.field1`. But as mentioned above this entire strategy doesn't work if you need hyphens in your field names. For that I'd recommend using a template filter, see: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/

Comment: Ok, I modified the fields so that they are just a single word, the branch name, but I still can't get the value from the field_reader.  I have the variable {{branch}} that equals the real branch name, ex 'mybranch1'   I try printing "{{field_reader.{{branch}}}}", and I get a 500 error saying "Could not parse the remainder: '{{branch' from 'field_reader.{{branch'".  If I try printing "{{field_reader.branch}}", I don't get anything, because it is looking for a field with the name "branch", not the value of the branch variable, "mybranch1".

Comment: Maybe I should ask this as a new question.

Comment: One thing that is for sure not possible is nested template variables. In Django, ``{{ foo {{ bar }} }}`` will never work. But this type of thing really shouldn't be necessary anyway.

In any event if you do open a new question link me to it. What I would find really helpful is if you put right in the question your  'vision' for the syntax. In your question I think I misunderstood; in ``bug.bug_id``, ``bug_id`` is itself a variable? This type of syntax is simply not supported, same as in Python where you can't do ``x = 'keys'; {}.x`` as an equivalent for ``{}.keys``.

Comment: In Python, what you *would* do is ``getattr({}, x)`` which *is* equivalent to ``{}.keys`` (given that ``x == 'keys'``). Out of the box, Django templates provide no equivalent to this, however if you need it, you can create a template filter which will allow you to do the same thing. (see: https://push.cx/2007/django-template-tag-for-dictionary-access)

Comment: New question added. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27287717/django-getting-related-model-data-in-a-specific-order-in-the-template

Answer (score 0):

You could use a nested loop to iterate over the related scrubs of each bug.

```
{% for scrub in bug.scrublines.all() %}
    <td>scrub</td>
{% endfor %}
```

Or use `scrub.field` if you only want print a specific field of the scrub.

** edit **

Because of your models, there will have many scrubs for a bug. So the right way to access them is using the defined `related_name` (scrubslines) and and the `all` method