# Django: getting related model data in a specific order in the template

Tags: django

This is a continuation of a previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27209200/django-how-to-get-a-named-related-field-in-a-template/).

I'm making a bug scrub website that pulls from a Bugzilla database.  Developers make requests to backport bugs to different branches, and this website keeps track of the requests and the scrubbing progress.

The main model is Bugs which has all of the bug details copied from Bugzilla.

I also have a Branches model of all of the different software branches.

```
class Branch(models.Model): 
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    flag_id = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    flag_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    version = models.CharField(max_length=10)
```

The main page on the website is a table.  The view walks through the Branches and inserts a header cell with the branch name into a headers list in a specific order that is sent to the template.

Each bug will have one or more unlocks request for different branches.  At first I created a separate field in the Bugs model for each branch name, but I don't want to have to edit the model/view/template each time we add or retire a branch.

So as an alternative I added a model called Flags, that has a FK to the bug_id, and the branch.

```
class Flags(models.Model):
    bug_id = models.ForeignKey(Bugs,related_name='flaglines')
    branch = models.ForeignKey(Branch)
```

I also have a model Scrub, which contains the scrub info for each bug.

```
class Scrub(models.Model):
    bug_id = models.ForeignKey(Bugs,related_name='scrublines')
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    time = models.DateTimeField()
    field = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

What I need to figure out how to do, is get the flags (and scrub) data from the related model, and place them in the correct order when the table gets displayed.

My current idea, is in the view, walk through each bug, and then walk through each branch (I can get them in the same order as the headers).  For each branch, check if there is a flag and scrub, and then add them to a dictionary.  If there were no flags or scrubs, the dictionary would just have empty strings as placeholders.  The dictionary for each branch gets added to a 'flags' list that gets added to the queryset data for that bug.

Then in the template, for each bug, walk through each of the flag/scrub lists, and put the dict values into their proper cell in the table.

An example of what the table should look like is this:

```
| Bug   |  Branch 1 |  Branch 2 | Branch 3| other fields...
----------------------------------------------------------
| 1234  |           | ?(flag)   | +(flag) | other data
| 2345  | ?(flag)   |           | ?(flag) | other data
| 3456  |           |           | ?(flag) | other data
```

I hope that is clear.

Is that the best way to accomplish this, or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I came up with, and it works, but I'm not sure if there is a more efficient way to do it.

```
branches = Branch.objects.filter(is_active=True)
bugs = Bugs.objects.filter(**filter_kwargs).order_by(*orderby_args)
for bug in bugs:
    flags_list = []                                 # list to hold dictionaries
    for branch in branches:
         flags_dict = {'branch':branch}             # dictionary for this branch
         try:
            flags_dict['flag'] = bug.flaglines.get(branch=branch)
         except Flags.DoesNotExist:
            flags_dict['flag'] = None
         try:
            flags_dict['scrub'] = bug.scrublines.get(field=branch.name).value
         except Scrub.DoesNotExist:
            flags_dict['scrub'] = None
        flags_list.append(flags_dict)
    bug.allflags = flags_list
```

Then in the template:

```
{% for bug in bugs %}
<tr class="bugrow" >
    <td><a name="{{bug.bug_id}}">{{bug.bug_id}}</a></td>
    {% for flag in bug.allflags %}
        <td>{% if flag.flag %}{{flag.flag}} {%if flag.scrub%}<br>({{flag.scrub}}){%endif%}{%endif%}</td>
    {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Why don't you filter by branch at the start?

Comment: Do you mean in the view?  I have to show all of the bugs, regardless of the branches that they were requested in.